# Last item in list cut off when using cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport for scrollbar

Tags: html, css, typescript, scrollbar

I am using cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport to make a scrollbar. It works well, except that the last element is always cut off, no matter how long the list is nor how much i set the itemSize parameter to. (I am using angular 8)
[picture of cut off last element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlakb.png)

This is my code

```css
  .gkz-viewport {
    height: 150px;
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    
    .cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .item {

    }
  }
```

```html
 <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport class="gkz-viewport" [itemSize]="3">
  <li *cdkVirtualFor="let app of apps" >
    <custom-apps-row [app]="app" ></custom-apps-row>
  </li>
  </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: no, i just re-wrote the whole page unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Set itemSize property of scroll-viewport to row height in px

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Remove or Change the color of cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport scrollbar. Please try this.

```
.cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport {
    color: mat-color(#fff, 300);
    transition: color 0.2s linear;

    &:hover {
      color: mat-color(#fff, 400);
    }
  }

  *::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
  }

  *::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: mat-color(#fff, 100);
  }

  *::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0;
  }
```